# What happened to the qtbase5-dbg package in Zesty?

Tags: package-management, qt, debugging, 17.04

I am attempting to install the debug symbols for the Qt core library using the following command, which worked perfectly fine in 16.10:

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dbg
```

However, this doesn't work in Zesty:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dbg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package qtbase5-dbg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'qtbase5-dbg' has no installation candidate
```

Upon closer inspection, I have discovered that none of the other Qt packages have their accompanying `*-dbg` package available any more.

What happened to these packages and how do I obtain the debug symbols?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I submitted this question to the `ubuntu-devel-discuss` mailing list and Mattia Rizzolo responded with [the following reply](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2017-April/017388.html):

> Debian is slowly dropping manual debug symbol packages (-dbg) in favour
>   of automatic ones (-dbgsym).
>
> https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2015/12/msg00262.html
>
> Ubuntu have automatic debug packages (.ddebs) since ever, and in case a
>   manual -dbg package exists it transitionally pulls it in:
>   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages
>
> I know a little work happened to make Ubuntu build debug packages as
>   does Debian now, I guess this work will (very) slowly make them
>   converge.

This is a little bit frustrating because not only is this not stated anywhere obvious but https://packages.ubuntu.com doesn't display `.ddeb` files and creates the mistaken impression that the `-dbgsym` packages don't exist.

---

### Now for the solution.

Create a file named `ddebs.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` with the following contents:

```
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com zesty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com zesty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com zesty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

<sup><sup>* You will likely need root privileges to create the file</sup></sup>

You will then need to run `apt-get update` to refresh the list of packages. The package that provides debug symbols for the Qt core library is named `libqt5core5a-dbgsym` and can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5core5a-dbgsym
```

Comment: Any idea what has happened to it in artful? I've tried the above, but I can't find any qt5 -dbgsym packages (though I can find other dbgsym packages).

Comment: Your solution doesn't fully work out of the box: we need to add the signing key (see your own link to Ubuntu wiki for details). After this yes, it does work.

Comment: for the signing key install  ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring

Comment: Works for my after also installing  `sudo apt install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring`.

Comment: How to make this work in Ubuntu 22.04? Do i just relplace `zesty` with `jammy` ?