# How to get debug symbols for QT5 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, qt

I have the following stack trace from QT. I want to get more detail, but apparently I need some kind of debug symbols for QT5 to see more.

However, I have not been able to figure out how. There is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904451/what-happened-to-the-qtbase5-dbg-package-in-zesty) but I am not on Zesty, I am on Focal. The suggested solution does not appear to work here anymore.

There is no qt5core-dbg or qt5base-dbg package either now.

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7ffff0b7bbc0 (LWP 31883)):
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
        set = {__val = {0 <repeats 12 times>, 228, 140737488338864, 140737488338864, 7758946189198844672}}
        pid = <optimized out>
        tid = <optimized out>
        ret = <optimized out>
#1  0x00007ffff5397859 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
        save_stage = 1
        act = {__sigaction_handler = {sa_handler = 0x7fffffffc058, sa_sigaction = 0x7fffffffc058}, sa_mask = {__val = {140737488339488, 140737488339496, 140737354022076, 140737488338896, 140737354046956, 3, 140737312309764, 0, 7758946189198844672, 140737488339032, 140737322294875, 3, 140737488339032, 140737488339520, 140737312310041, 0}}, sa_flags = 1318150912, sa_restorer = 0x7ffff61a1e5b}
        sigs = {__val = {32, 0 <repeats 15 times>}}
#2  0x00007ffff57ebaad in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007ffff5dcd7ae in QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007ffff5dce708 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007ffff59f2f55 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007ffff5dd0543 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::init() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00007ffff640b3bd in QApplicationPrivate::init() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x000055555555917f in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe718) at /mnt/c/source/myProject/main.cpp:105
        rc = 0
        a = <incomplete type>
        args = {_vptr.CLfxArgs = 0x0, m_threads = 0, m_autoFile = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_firstFile = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_fragDir = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_forceFirst = false, m_materialsDir = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_meshFile = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_vmFile = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_logFile = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_lfxLog = false, m_testNum = 0, m_iterNum = 0, m_batch = false, m_noInit = false, m_qstarFile = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_fragFuncNum = 42076, m_workingDir = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x7ffff5582510}}
        pTest = 0x0
        dAccumTime = 0
        batch = false
        szMsg = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}
```

Please tell me there is a way without compiling all of QT. I really can't go that route.

My qt5 version is:

- qtbase5-dev/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
- qt5-default: 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages#Getting_-dbgsym.ddeb_packages

Comment: Do `kubuntu-debug-installer` and `kubuntu-debug-installer-dbg` possibly have what you need?

Comment: It seems you have already found the dbgsym solution - what happened when you tried it? "Does not appear to work anymore" doesn't mean anything useful

Comment: @muru I went ahead and followed those instructions, and they appear to work. However, looking for qt5base-dbg, qt5core-dbg, qtbas5-dbg still gets 'Unable to locate package'. Is the name incorrect or am I missing a step? EDIT: libqt5core5a-dbgsym appears to work. I will test if this fixes the stacktrace. Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded and searched the packages file `cat ./Packages | grep qt5 | grep dbg | grep core` and came up with `libqt5core5a-dbgsym` but you could probably do `apt-cache search qt5 | grep core | grep dbg` if you have the repository installed and possibly leave off one of the greps or change the search terms, etc.

Comment: I went ahead and got `libqt5core5a-dbgsym`, though it made no difference to the stack trace unfortunately. Maybe QTCreator has to be 'pointed' to these symbols somehow, I am unsure.

Comment: @TylerShellberg What about the [automatic resolution / installation of necessary packages section](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages#Automatic_Resolution_.2F_Installation_of_necessary_packages)?